Is there a word for suicide that's caused by discrimination, harassment, or abuse?
I've tried to find a word for suicide that's caused by discrimination, harassment, abuse, or isolation, but I can't find it, there's bullycide but it's not very accurate, does anyone know what's the word for that?

We tend to use 'suicide' for all types of self-destruction; there is no special word for the type of death you are asking about.

If you are experiencing feelings, or having intrusive thoughts, about suicide, or you are being bullied, PLEASE seek help from a trusted teacher, a parent, or your doctor.

No, in English there is not.
That begs two queries at least:
Is English your first or main language?
Either way, why might different kinds of suicide be interesting, let alone important?
Whatever else, I echo Michael Harvey's view that on the slightest suggestion, you seek help from a trusted teacher, parent, or doctor or anyone in a similar position, such as priest or student counsellor.

@RobbieGoodwin +1 for priest or counsellor.

@RobbieGoodwin - I had to study Suicide: A Study in Sociology (1897, a seminal sociology text by Émile Durkheim). Even now, any sociology student or teacher will know it very well.  It is regarded as one of the most important books Durkheim ever wrote.

Those factors are certainly recognized (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7891495/) but there is no "everyday" word in use by speakers of English that refers to suicide that is a result of one or more of those stressors.

@MichaelHarvey Thanks for that and all please note, in my view all up- or down-votes should always be justified.

@RobbieGoodwin - I always justify up and down votes in my head before I cast them; I do not always feel inclined to make the thought process public, and I firmly believe that Stack Exchange policy of not requiring it (or even encouraging it) is the right one. Also, (especially) votes applied to comments are not worth the paper they are written on.

@MichaelHarvey That's a long debate which we'll doubtless be struck down for having here. Until then, I do see that any upvote says 'I broadly agree' and any down-vote against a single phrase will usually be equally clear and simple.
I also think the situation changes when either an Answer involves several clauses or, as in ELL more than most areas, delicate nuances are involved.

@RobbieGoodwin - I think that explaining a downvote can start an argument or feud, and people who ought to know better have accused me of downvoting their answers, merely because I disagreed with something in them at roughly the same time that someone else downvoted them. There are even people (happily, rare) who watch your rep score for the change a downvote causes, and assume it was you when it was someone else.

@MichaelHarvey Yes but don't you think an argument or feud is more likely without, than with an explanation? Either way, thanks again!

@RobbieGoodwin - how can anyone argue with an anonymous downvoter? You do get people protesting about downvotes, but it is not a good look, and good never comes of it.

English doesn't have a special noun to identify a person who took their own life because of discrimination, harassment, abuse, or isolation.
But we can succinctly reference such a situation by saying the "victim"...

was driven to suicide (by hostile agents, or unbearable circumstances)


A person can be driven to suicide by insanity, or a profound sense of guilt. It doesn't exactly comply with the OP's word request, but neither does swmcdonnell's.

My answer was that such a word does not exist.

No. There's only one type of successful suicide, which is suicide. regardless of the person's motivation for doing it.
Unsuccessful suicide is attempted suicide.
